# What's the Helicarrier's name?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shield

Military craft are named, especially the bigger craft.  In *Avengers*, S.H.I.E.L.D. has a Helicarrier, but I don't recall it ever being referred to by name.

Does the Helicarrier have a name, and if so, what is it?

Comment: "LST" or "Large Slow Target"

Comment: Geoff. It’s Geoff Helicarrier.

Comment: American sea going vessels (which technically the Hellicarrier from Avengers was) don't require names, but they do require vessel/hull numbers.

Comment: "BFH" for "Big Fine Helicarrier"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### While the MCU version of the Helicarrier does not appear to have a Name designation, it was given a number, #64. The Earth-616 versions did have designations (that were strangely rarely used...). It is not yet known what criteria S.H.I.E.L.D. has used to name the Helicarriers.

**From the MCU Wiki:**

The **[known Helicarrier designations](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Helicarrier#Known_Helicarriers)** were

- Helicarrier No. 64 (the original Helicarrier)
- What were called the Insight Project Helicarriers:

  - Helicarrier IN-01
  - Helicarrier IN-02
  - Helicarrier IN-03

Perhaps the designation for the original helicarrier is a design number, or in some way related to a military ship numerical designation. No name is currently known to be associated with the first helicarrier design.

**From the Canon Marvel Universe, Earth-616:**

> First appearing in Strange Tales #135 (August, 1965), the Earth-616 **[S.H.I.E.L.D. Helicarriers](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D._Helicarrier)** were constructed in secret. There are at least nine Helicarriers which have been built over the decades, and at least two have been in simultaneous service in the last decade on several occasions. Also, at least seven Helicarriers have been named over the years:
>
> - Luxor (not yet seen - a class prototype)
> - Behemoth (smaller version used by S.H.I.E.L.D.'s Godzilla Squad)
> - Hermes (allegedly scuttled after being hijacked by the Red Skull)
> - Argus (a Luxor-class Helicarrier)
> - Black Hawk (destroyed in action against the Hydra-Hand alliance)
> - Alpha
> - Pericles V (infiltrated by the vampiric Order of Tyrana and scuttled
>   by Blade)
> - Iliad (currently in use)

Answer (score -2):

CV-64 was the USS Constellation, a Kitty Hawk class aircraft carrier. Decommissioned in 2003, scrapped in 2015.  As The Avengers movie was released in 2012, it was available.  It’s also in the canon per the Wikipedia entry on the helicarrier (even mentions USS Constellation).  That said, the size on screen makes it look like new construction versus a rebuild, and it’s just called the helicarrier in the films IIRC.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any actual evidence that it was called the *Constellation* in the MCU?  Note that it's not uncommon to rename ships when they are transferred.